# Can preg_replace_callback() preserve elements of the variable?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I've got a series of large markdown strings that contain URLs, most of the URLs are fine, but a number of them were broken when changing the formatting, they had a number of dashes ("-") changed into whitespace characters.

I've been trying to use preg_replace_callback() to fix these when they are loaded in PHP.

Examples:

```
[Site Name](http://www.siteurl.com/this-is-the-website broken url)
```

Since these are all contained with in large strings (that usually have 4-5 paragraphs of text) and may have 1-3+ URLs in the text, I need to iterate over them, capture the string, remove the whitespace replacing it with a dash and return it to the right location.

Currently I've got the matching taken care of:

```
$postBody = preg_replace_callback("^(\([A-Za-z\:\/0-9\-.\s]*\))^",'urlcallback', $postBody);
```

And I've tried to create the function:

```
function urlcallback ($matches) {
static $id = 0;
$matches[$id] = preg_replace("^\s^", "-", $matches);
return $matches[$id];
$id++;
}
```

My understanding of preg_replace_callback() was that it would call the function each time it encounters a match in the string, and place the return of the function at that spot, but as I am getting the error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in cleanup.php at line 139
```

And line 139 is my early $postBody declaration, I assume that preg_replace_callback() is dealing with all the matches at the same time, so I'm not sure how to pass them back into the string while only changing the whitespaces in each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be this line:

```
$matches[$id] = preg_replace("^\s", "-", $matches);
```

As `$matches` is an array not a string value.

It should be:

```
$matches[$id] = preg_replace('/\s/', "-", $matches[0]);
```

`$matches[0]` represents whole matched string from `preg_replace_callback` function call.

Comment: The line is:
$matches[$id] = preg_replace("^\s^", "-", $matches); using ^ as delimeter

Comment: Nope that gives me the error "Undefined offset at 2"

Comment: ok try: `$matches[$id] = preg_replace('/\s/', "-", $matches[0]);`

Comment: Awesome that worked! Do you mind explaining the changes?

Comment: `$matches[0]` represents whole matched string from `preg_replace_callback` function call. I've updated the answer as well.